# How to insert an array after a specific key in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the below data in my user column.

```
{
   "user_details":[
      [
         "First Name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "Middle Name",
         true
      ],
      [
         "Phone Number",
         true
      ],
      [
         "Email",
         false
      ],
      [
         "Address",
         true
      ],
   ],
   "user_payment_details":[
      
   ]
}
```

Now I want to add check if **Middle Name** is present in the data and if it present then I want to add **Last Name** after **Middle Name** with the 2nd array value with the value(true or false) of **Middle Name**. I have tried the below method, but it is not working as expected. Can anyone suggest the changes or new code?

```
$datas = Test::all();
foreach ($datas as $data)
{
    foreach ($data->user['user_details'] as $key => $u) {
        if ($u[0] == 'Middle Name' && $u[1]) {
            array_splice($data->user['user_details'][$key], $key+1, 0, [["Last Name", true]]);
        } else {
            array_splice($data->user['user_details'][$key], $key+1, 0, [["Last Name", false]]);
        }
        $data->save();
    }
};
```

Comment: Does the position really matter?

Comment: That's invalid JSON btw

Comment: @brombeer Yes. I want **Last Name** after **Middle Name**.

Comment: @brombeer I don't think so. It is **jsonb** column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [];
foreach ($data->user['user_details'] as $key => $value) {
    $array[] = $value;
    if ($value[0] == 'Middle Name') {
        $array[] = ['Last Name', $value[1]];
    }
}
$data->user['user_details'] = $array;
```